# How to continue sending requests to server to get next items in loadAfter() even though list being passed to callback is empty?

Tags: android, android-paging-library

I am using paging library to handle the pagination.

Here is my `DataSource` class where requests are sent to server.

```
class HistoryDataSource() : PageKeyedDataSource<Int, DummyObject>() {

override fun loadInitial(
    params: LoadInitialParams<Int>,
    callback: LoadInitialCallback<Int, DummyObject>) {

     //First load
}

override fun loadAfter(
    params: LoadParams<Int>,
    callback: LoadCallback<Int, DummyObject>) {

    authApi.loadHistoryForCard(params.key.toInt(), params.requestedLoadSize, cardToken)
        .subscribe({ response ->

         //HERE I DELETE THE FIRST N ITEMS ACCORDING TO SOME CONDITION.
         //THEN PASS LIST TO CALLBACK

            callback.onResult(
                    response.list,
                    params.key + 1
            )

        },{
            //handle error here
    }).also {}
}

override fun loadBefore(
    params: LoadParams<Int>,
    callback: LoadCallback<Int, DummyObject>) {
}
}
```

BUT: when I am deleting certain items in the list, I might end up with a with a situation where all items are deleted and list might be empty. Then, I need to pass this empty list to callback.

The issue is that **if I pass empty list to callback, paging library thinks that this is the end of the list**. But actually it is not. There are still more items in the server.

How can I continue sending requests to load next bunk of items even though I pass empty list to callback?

Or (paraphrasing the question) How can I let paging library know that it is not the end of the list (even though i passing empty list to callback)?

Comment: Why are you passing empty list ? You just have to check that Your ListView or RecyclerView is scrolled up to end or not and then call the service to fetch the data.

Comment: @JaiminModi I am not passing empty list all the time. Please note that I pass only empty list if all the items in my list matches my conditions and gets deleted.

Comment: Please explain how your server gives you response according to page count or any other logic ? You can make your own paging implementation and use it according to your need.

Comment: blablabla.com/history/pageNum/pageSiz/userId Here pageNum is number of the page. pageSize is the size of the page. userId is the id of the user. Yes, I know that I can implement my paging. But I need to use paging library.